# How to start decrementing an array after incrementing in Java

Tags: java

new at Java programming, wanted to know how I could decrement the number of rows in my matrix after incrementing them upto 3. I tried the while loop but I guess I couldn't input a correct condition

```
double duo_array[][] = {
        {1*0},
        {1*1,1*2},
        {1*3,1*4,1*5},
        {1*6,1*7,1*8},
        {1*9,1*10},
        {1*11}
    } ;
    int i, j = 0;
    //unfinished business
    for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<i+1;j++) 
            while(j!= 0 ) {
                j--;
    }
            System.out.println(duo_array[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Comment: what is the output you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {double duo_array[][] = {
        {1*0},
        {1*1,1*2},
        {1*3,1*4,1*5},
        {1*6,1*7,1*8},
        {1*9,1*10},
        {1*11}
    } ;
    int i, j = 0;
    //unfinished business
    for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<duo_array[i].length;j++)
            System.out.print(duo_array[i][j] + " ");
            while(j!= 0 ) {
                j--;
    }
//              System.out.println(duo_array[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

I have changed one condition : j < duo_array[i].length

and the position of sysout

Comment: What is while loop doing here ?

Comment: don't know, didn't want to remove garbage code from this. maybe @Qasim can tell

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you want to print it like below -

```
0.0 
1.0 2.0 
3.0 4.0 5.0 
6.0 7.0 8.0 
9.0 10.0 
11.0
```

Here is your unfinished business -

```
//unfinished business
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
        if(i<3){
        for(int j=0;j<i+1;j++) 
            System.out.print(duo_array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        else {
            for(int j=0;j<duo_array.length-i;j++)
            System.out.print(duo_array[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It worked but I cant understand this part             for(int j=0;j<duo_array.length-i;j++)

Comment: This is just mathematical relation to control j's upper limit. When i is 3, j will go max to 2 (j<6-3); when i is 4, j will go to 1 max and when i is 5, j will go till 0. Try with pen & paper.